# Is the limit of a family of sheaves a sheaf?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra, sheaf-theory, limits-colimits

So, I can prove that the kernel of a morphism of sheaves or a product of sheaves is a sheaf, but I do not know how to prove in general that $lim F_{i}$ is a sheaf for $F_{i}$ sheaves. I know that if we regard the $F_{i}$ as presheaves, then the limit exists in the category of presheaves but I do not know how to argue about the category of sheaves.

Comment: Which direction do the maps go? $F_i\to F_{i+1}$ (which would give direct limit / category theoretical colimit, assuming $i\in\Bbb N$), or $F_{i}\to F_{i-1}$ (which would give the inverse limit / category theoretical limit)?

Comment: Prove that glueing holds for limits. You know how elements of a limit look.

Comment: Actually, I know that the limit exists in the category of presheaves, so you mean that the limit is given by sending a $U$ open to $limF_{i}(U)$. But what an element in $limF_{i}(U)$ looks like?

Comment: A compatible family, as any limit in sets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall we have an adjoint pair $a \dashv i$, where $i : Sh(X) \to PSh(X)$ is the inclusion of sheaves into presheaves, and $a : PSh(X) \to Sh(X)$ is the [sheafification functor](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/sheafification).

Now since right adjoints preserve limits we can compute the limit of a diagram in $Sh(X)$ as though it were a diagram in $PSh(X)$. That is, if $D$ is a diagram in $Sh(X)$, then computing $\lim_D \mathcal{F}_\alpha$ as though the $\mathcal{F}_\alpha$s were merely presheaves will always result in a sheaf.

If you want to be super precise, this is because

$$
\lim_D i \mathcal{F}_\alpha \cong i \left ( \lim_D \mathcal{F}_\alpha \right )
$$

Notice, however, that right adjoints do *not* preserve colimits. So $\text{colim}_D \mathcal{F}_\alpha$ need *not* be a sheaf if we interpret the $\mathcal{F}_\alpha$ as presheaves! We solve this problem by sheafifying afterwards:

$$\text{colim}_D \mathcal{F}_\alpha \cong a \left ( \text{colim}_D i \mathcal{F}_\alpha \right )$$

---

For concreteness, notice this is analogous to the situation of abelian groups sitting inside of groups.

We have an adjoint pair $ab \dashv i$, where $ab(G)$ is the abelianization functor, and $i$ is the inclusion of abelian groups into groups.

Then, since right adjoints preserve limits, the limit of abelian groups is exactly the same as the limit computed as though they were merely groups: $A \times B$ means the same thing whether $A$ and $B$ are abelian, or whether they are just groups.

However, the colimit of abelian groups is *not* the same thing as the colimit of groups!

The colimit $A \ast B$ computed in $\mathsf{Grp}$ is the free product, whereas the colimit $A \oplus B$ as computed in $\mathsf{Ab}$ is the direct sum! But notice that the direct sum *is* the abelianization of the free product! That is, $A \oplus B \cong ab \left ( A \ast B \right )$.

The situation is entirely analogous for sheaves as a subcategory of presheaves.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: the thing is that knowing that the limit exists in $\mathsf{PSh}(X)$ does not imply that the limit also exists in $\mathsf{Sh}(X)$, right? As you say, the inclusion $i:\mathsf{Sh}(X)\to\mathsf{PSh}(X)$ does preserve limits, but this is only useful info provided that _you already know that the limit exists in the domain_. That is, this only works for saying "if some diagram of sheaves has a limiting cone in $\mathsf{Sh}(X)$ then this is also a limiting cone in $\mathsf{PSh}(X)$"

Comment: @ElíasGuisado -- That's a good observation! But here $i$ also creates limits since $Sh(X)$ is a _full_ subcategory. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2344600/right-adjoint-functor-fully-faithful) for one proof.

Comment: @ElíasGuisado You are correct. The actual proof is that because $i$ is fully faithful and has a left adjoint $a$, $i$ must be monadic. And monadic functors create limits.

Comment: If $\lim_i\mathcal{F}_i$ is a limit in $\mathsf{PSh}(X)$, where $\mathcal{F}_i$ are sheaves, from the fact that the inclusion $\mathsf{Sh}(X)\to\mathsf{PSh}(X)$ creates limits we will get a limiting cone $\{f_i:\mathcal{F}\to\mathcal{F}_i\}_i$ in $\mathsf{Sh}(X)$ which is also a limiting cone in $\mathsf{PSh}(X)$, so therefore we will have that $\mathcal{F}\cong\lim_i\mathcal{F}_i$. I think that it would be left to argue that a presheaf that is isomorphic to a sheaf must be a sheaf, to make it secure that $\lim_i\mathcal{F}_i$ will always be a sheaf.

Comment: (that is, that $\mathsf{Sh}(X)$ is a replete subcategory of $\mathsf{PSh}(X)$.)

Answer (score 2):

A proof by HallaSurvivor was given using an existence of a sheafification. That is, of a left adjoint to the inclusion $\mathsf{PSh}(X)\to\mathsf{PSh}(X)$ (so $\mathsf{Sh}(X)$ is a reflective subcategory of $\mathsf{PSh}(X)$). By theory of reflective subcategories it follows that the inclusion creates limits. I will here show that the inclusion strictly creates object-wise computable limits, without invoking any sheafification. (The expressions "creates limits" and "strictly creates limits" are explained in definitions 3.3.1 and 3.3.7 of [Riehl's book](https://math.jhu.edu/%7Eeriehl/context.pdf)).

Two important facts must be used. Let $\mathsf{I}, \mathsf{J}$ be a small categories.

1. A diagram of functors $\{F_i:\mathsf{C}\to\mathsf{D}\}_{i\in \mathsf{J}}$ (that is, a diagram $\mathsf{J}\to\mathsf{D}^\mathsf{C}$) which has object-wise limit (i.e., for each $c\in\mathsf{C}$, the limit $\lim_{\mathsf{J}}F_i(c)$ exists in $\mathsf{D}$) also has limit and it is computable object-wise. That is, $\lim_\mathsf{J}F_i$ exists in $\mathsf{D}^\mathsf{C}$ and $(\lim_\mathsf{J}F_i)(c)\cong\lim_\mathsf{J}F_i(c)$, for each $c\in\mathsf{C}$. You can read about this fact [here](https://unapologetic.wordpress.com/2007/06/23/limits-in-functor-categories/) and also in Proposition 3.3.9 of [Riehl's book](https://math.jhu.edu/%7Eeriehl/context.pdf).
2. Limits commute with limits: if we have a diagram $\{c_{ij}\}_{\mathsf{I}\times\mathsf{J}}$ in $\mathsf{C}$ (i.e., a diagram $\mathsf{I}\times\mathsf{J}\to\mathsf{C}$) for which $\lim_{j\in\mathsf{J}}c_{ij}$ exists for all $i\in\mathsf{I}$, then $\lim_{i\in\mathsf{I}}\lim_{j\in\mathsf{J}}c_{ij}$ exists if and only if $\lim_{(i,j)\in\mathsf{I}\times\mathsf{J}}c_{ij}$ exists, and in this case
   $$
   \lim_{i\in\mathsf{I}}\lim_{j\in\mathsf{J}}c_{ij}\cong\lim_{(i,j)\in\mathsf{I}\times\mathsf{J}}c_{ij}.
   $$
   The same holds if we swap $\mathsf{I}$ and $\mathsf{J}$. Thus, if all the involved limits exist,
   $$
   \lim_{i\in\mathsf{I}}\lim_{j\in\mathsf{J}}c_{ij}\cong\lim_{j\in\mathsf{J}}\lim_{i\in\mathsf{I}}c_{ij}.
   $$
   The analogous result holds for colimits. A quick search in google with "limits commute with limits in category theory" should give explanations of this fact.

We are ready to give our proof. Suppose $\{\mathcal{F}_i\}_{i\in\mathsf{J}}$ is a diagram of sheaves (a functor $\mathsf{J}\to\mathsf{Sh}(X)$) that has a limit in $\mathsf{PSh}(X)$. For the proof, we need to suppose that the diagram $\{\mathcal{F}_i\}_{i\in\mathsf{J}}$ has object-wise limits. That is, for each $U\in\operatorname{Ouv}(X)$, we assume that $\lim_i\mathcal{F}(U)$ exists in the category where our sheaves takes values. This would be true were this category complete, as it is for the usual categories ($\mathsf{Set},\mathsf{Ring},\mathsf{Mod}_R,\mathsf{Ab},\dots$). Then, for any open set $U\subset X$ and any open cover $\bigcup_\alpha U_\alpha=U$, we have

\begin{aligned}
&\phantom{\cong}\operatorname{eq}\left(
\prod_\alpha(\lim_i\mathcal{F}_i)(U_\alpha)\rightrightarrows
\prod_{\alpha,\beta}(\lim_i\mathcal{F}_i)(U_\alpha\cap U_\beta)
\right)\cong\\
&\cong\operatorname{eq}\left(
\prod_\alpha\lim_i\mathcal{F}_i(U_\alpha)\rightrightarrows
\prod_{\alpha,\beta}\lim_i\mathcal{F}_i(U_\alpha\cap U_\beta)
\right)
&&\text{by fact 1}\\
&\cong\lim_i\operatorname{eq}\left(
\prod_\alpha\mathcal{F}_i(U_\alpha)\rightrightarrows
\prod_{\alpha,\beta}\mathcal{F}_i(U_\alpha\cap U_\beta)
\right)&&\text{by fact 2}\\
&\cong\lim_i\mathcal{F}_i(U)&\text{since }\mathcal{F}_i\text{ are sheaves}\\
&\cong(\lim_i\mathcal{F}_i)(U)&&\text{by fact 1}.
\end{aligned}
So $\lim_i\mathcal{F}_i$ satisfies the sheaf condition.